# Is there any FAN upgrade option for HP 15 da1032?

Tags: cooling, heat-sink

**Hello community**. I just bought an HP laptop (HP 15 da1032) about a month ago, but i noticed that the laptop was heating with minimum amount of work load (i tried installing **Eclipse**),it goes around (39 C), and there is only ONE fan and ONE heat pipe for cooling the CPU ([i7 8565u](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/149091/intel-core-i7-8565u-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-60-ghz.html)) and the GPU (NVIDIA MX-130), and the laptop back panel is Plastic. Now i want to know is there a better fan or heat pipe for my laptop? or is there any back panel that fit with my model? i searched online but i couldn't find something talk about replacement.

here is a picture of my laptop inside:

[image]

PS: There is some videos on YouTube trying to re-apply the **Thermal Paste**, i thought my laptop would not need this cause it's new.

and,  i heard that back panels that are **Aluminum** or **Magnesium alloy**  will do a better job for cooling, will this really help with my laptop? i was wondered if it's available for my laptop model. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You are left with what the manufacturer deemed an acceptable cooling solution. Also, there are no replacement parts made from different materials.

Changing/reapplying high quality thermal paste can give better results, even if the device is new. Liquid metal compounds offer the lowest thermal resistance, but can cause damage to your machine, both in the short term (they are electrically conductive) and in the long term (they don't get along well e.g. with copper).

But it seems like you might be seeing a problem where there is none. The only temperature you mentioned is 39°C, which is completely safe and normal for modern mobile CPUs. Under load, they usually run above 90°C.

Comment: MechEng is right on. The CPU T-Junction is rated at 100 degrees C per https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/149091/intel-core-i7-8565u-processor-8m-cache-up-to-4-60-ghz.html .  NVIDIA does not provide a ceiling temp for the MX130 in its published specs https://www.geforce.com/hardware/notebook-gpus/nvidia-geforce-mx130/specifications but I doubt 39 Centigrade would be a problem for it, either. Don't overdo the thermal paste if you decide to change it; see https://www.gamersnexus.net/guides/3346-thermal-paste-application-benchmark-too-much-thermal-paste